# Trying to list user and post information from (wp_includes/post.php ) causes Fatal error

Tags: wp-admin, admin

I Got Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo()

I tried using:

- `get_userdata( $userid );`
- `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`
- `$current_user =  get_currentuserinfo();`

in wp_includes/post.php

I need to update a table whenever a post is published in admin portion and I tried to retrieve above details but it causes an error.

Comment: How can you even think of editing a core file?? Never, do this.
Also, share the whole code where you want to use the current user-id.

Comment: Hello @johnFrancis. Please put some code here i.e. what you did? and in which file you are trying to get the user information.

Comment: Chances are your calling the function before it's defined. What hook is your code running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please revert your WP core file and create a plugin instead. For this type of functionality, you can use the [Publish Post hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post).

Assuming your custom table is in the same database as WordPress, and you want to save the email address of the current user:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'update_my_custom_table');
function update_my_custom_table() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $email = $current_user->user_email;
    global $wpdb;
    $addInfo = $wpdb->insert('wp_custom_table', "$email");
}
```

Hopefully this will get you started down the right path, so you can insert whatever data you're trying to add. There may be a better way than adding your own table, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, but you didn't mention much about your goal for the data.